# Cannot insert Phone Number into Database (MS Access File)

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2010

I'm creating a database app; with MS Access dataBase file. 
What happens is everything is inserted correctly, but not Phone Numbers.
When entering a Phone Number the Application i am working throws me an exception.

I've double checked my coding and my Database and can't figure out why this issue is caused.
Here's the part of the code.

```
    private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbCommand DBcmd = new OleDbCommand();
                DBcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DBcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_ClientInfo (FirstName, LastName, Address, ZipCode, City, State, Country, Language, PhoneNr, MobileNr)" + "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @ZipCode, @City, @State, @Country, @Language, @PhoneNr, @MobileNr)";
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txt_FirstName.Text);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txt_LastName.Text);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt_Address.Text);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", txt_ZipCode.Text);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txt_City.Text);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", txt_State.Text);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", ComboBox_Countries.SelectedItem);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Language", comboBox_Languages.SelectedItem);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNr", txt_PhoneNr.Text);
                DBcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNr", txt_MobileNr.Text);


                DBcmd.Connection = DBconnection;
                DBconnection.Open();

                DBcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DBconnection.Close();

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"d:\test.txt");
                file.WriteLine(ex);

                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LANGUAGE is a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) in MS-Access Jet. You need to encapsulate it in square brackets

```
DBcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_ClientInfo (FirstName, LastName, Address, ZipCode, " + 
                    "City, State, Country, [Language], PhoneNr, MobileNr)" + 
                    "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @ZipCode, " + 
                    "@City, @State, @Country, @Language, @PhoneNr, @MobileNr)";
```

If it is still possible, I suggest to change that column name. You will always find yourself in this predicament every time you use this table.

Comment: That makes sense, and solved my issue instantly. I completely forgot that there are some "reserved" words.
I've been here for hours trying to understad such a simple thing... Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 0):

You removed the exception you were getting, which was:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open
```

DBconnection is a variable scoped outside of this method, correct? The exception implies that you have already opened this connection someplace else and haven't closed it yet, so you can't open it again. You should either make sure you are closing and disposing of your connection properly every place it is used, or check the state of the connection in the code you posted and don't try to re-open it if it is already open.

Comment: Yes i edited (deleted the exception) because the exception i've initially posted wasn't the one i was previously getting. (Sorry by that)
Problem is now fixed.
Thanks for replying.